# XPath - is a date null

Tags: date, datetime, xpath, infopath2010

Using XPath, how do I figure out if a date or datetime field is null or blank?

I am using the concat method as a stand-in for the XPath if statement

```
concat(
substring(../preceding-sibling::my:PerDiem[1]/my:perDiemEnd, 1, ../preceding-sibling::my:PerDiem[1]/my:perDiemEnd = "" * string-length(../preceding-sibling::my:PerDiem[1]/my:perDiemEnd)),
substring(/my:ExpenseForm/my:ExpenseHeader/my:departureDateTime, 1, not(../preceding-sibling::my:PerDiem[1]/my:perDiemEnd = "") * string-length(/my:ExpenseForm/my:ExpenseHeader/my:departureDateTime))
)
```

---

More info:
In Infopath 2010, a repeating table has two date/time fields called perDiemStart and perDiemEnd.  In the repeating table, the next perDiemStart is the previous perDiemEnd.  This is easily done if the default value of perDiemStart is `../preceding-sibling::my:PerDiem[1]/my:perDiemEnd`

But for the first perDiemStart (since a previous perDiemEnd does not exist, I suppose it would be null/blank).  I want that first (blank) value to be a different: value of departureDateTime node

Node locations:

`/my:ExpenseForm/my:ExpenseHeader/my:departureDateTime`

`/my:ExpenseForm/my:PerDiemDetails/my:PerDiems/my:PerDiem/my:perDiemStart`

`/my:ExpenseForm/my:PerDiemDetails/my:PerDiems/my:PerDiem/my:perDiemEnd`

Comment: If you need a meaningful and useful answer, you need to provide a small sample XML document, to explain which nodes hold date values and what the result from the evaluation of the XPath expression should be. Please, edit the question and specify the missing, important information.

Answer (score 1):

To check if it is filled:

```
perDiemStart[text()]
```

To check if it is empty/null:

```
perDiemStart[not(text())]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syamp/archive/2011/03/13/fim-2010-xpath-how-to-check-null-value-on-a-datetime-attribute.aspx

Basically they detect null dates by getting the set of dates after an old date (e.g. 1900-01-01) and then using 'not' to see which nodes would be excluded.